# Visual Studio Android Emulator - Mashmallow Power State

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS Android Emulator for Marshmallow and want to test my application (Xamarin) in Doze mode.  The problem is the Emulator never seems to go to Doze mode.

Using adb I have issued the following commands, repeat step 2 again and again but the end result is always "Stepped to: ACTIVE".

1. adb shell dumpsys battery unplug.
2. adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.  In all documentation, post, forum they don't mention that you have to enable the deviceidle state.  Issue the following then run the two commands above.  Thanks.

adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable